# increase the separation of two lines in double bonds using chemfig package

Tags: errors, chemfig, pgfkeys

I was trying to draw a molecule using chemfig package where i would like to increase the spacing between the two lines of double bond. From the manual of chemfig, i came to know that by using the option *double bond sep = 3pt*, we can do it. But when i use the same in my file, i get the error **Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/double bond sep', to which you passed '3pt', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.**
I don't know how to resolve this.
MY MWE is as follow:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{B=C}~~~~~~
        \chemfig[double bond sep = 3pt]{B=C}\\
\end{document}
```

I had also tried another MWE as follows which also gives same error:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{chemfig}
    \begin{document}
    \chemfig{B=C}~~~~~~
            \chemfig{B=[,,,, double bond sep = 3pt]C}\\
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your first MWE works fine for me, however the second does not. Are both of them giving you the same error?

Comment: Which version of the `chemfig` package do you currently use?

Comment: @leandriis Package: chemfig 2017/05/20 v1.2e

Comment: @Alenanno first MWE is working in overleaf but nor working in mine document on doing copy paste. However second MWE is not working in overleaf as well as mine. I had just used this MWE to test as i predict it should work. And yes both MWE gives same error

Comment: Update your packages /  use a newer tex live version on overleaf. There was a syntax change in the chemfig package in 2018, hence the error messages you get. With a newer version of the chemfig package the document should compile just fine.